# Can $\sqrt{dt}$ in a Wiener process be interpreted as a differential form.

Tags: differential-geometry, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, differential-forms

If a particle follows a Wiener process $W(t)$, in physics, we often write that the infinitesimal displacement is:
$$dx\sim dW\sim\sqrt{dt}\mathcal{N}(0,1)$$

It makes sense if we treat $dt$ and $dx$ as infinitesimals, but can it be made rigourous when $dx$ is treated as a differential form? Does the square root of a differential form can be defined?

Comment: The traditional way of making this rigorous is not to give a meaning to $dW$ when it stands alone. What has a meaning is the Ito integral $\int_0^T X_t\,dW_t\,.$ The square-root over $dt$ is made rigorous by saying that the quadratic variation of $W$ is $t$. That being said: if someone comes up with more than a vague idea borrowed from differential forms I'd be very interested.